# Gulp-csscomb не работает с .sass

Tags: gulp, sass, javascript

Настроил csscomb для .css и все прекрасно работает, но для .sass настроить не получается.
Код в .sass минимально прост -

```
body
    background: #232323
```

Вот таск -

```
gulp.task( 'csscombsass', function( ){
    return gulp.src( config.paths.sass + '/**/*.sass' )
               .pipe( plumber( {errorHandler: notify.onError("<%= error.message %>")} ) )
               .pipe( csscombsass( ) )
               .pipe( gulp.dest( config.paths.sass ) );
} );
```

Где ошибки?

**UPD:** после создания вопроса нашел онлайн компилятор и с его помощью выявил проблему...
Если ставить четыре пробела, то все работает, но я ставлю табы...
Можно это исправить?

Comment: > Можно это исправить?

Исправить в настройках Вашего редактора/IDE - автоматическая конвертация табов в пробелы.

Comment: Странно что влияют табы, я тоже вместо пробелов их использую и у меня все прекрасно отрабатывает.
Может из-за того, что у вас стоит пробел в скобках csscombsass( )